# Effects of Switching to Primefaces 8.0 for ROMA layout

Tags: primefaces

I have newly started working with Primefaces. I had bought a ROMA layout last Christmas from PF. It was used with PF 7. Now if I switch to primefaces 8.0, would it break the ROMA layout ?
Or the layouts are agnostic of Primefaces versions?

Could someone please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: If you log into your PF PrimeStore account you will see there is a new ROMA layout version for you compatible with PF 8.0

Comment: Ah ok, but I did not have the ELITE license. I just have this personal license. So I did not expect to have free updates. But I went to https://www.primefaces.org/store/templates.xhtml and Could download the 2.2.0 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrimeTek has updated all Premium layouts for PF 8.0.  Please just log into your PrimeStore account and you will see a new version of your layout available for download.